# cant cast BTreeNode * to BTreeP &(typedef BTreeNode* BTreeP;)

Tags: c++, pointers, types, reference

I wrote a program about BTree, here's the code:

```
class BTreeNode 
{
public:
...
    BTreeNode* getChild(const int i);    
private:
...
};
typedef BTreeNode* BTreeP;

void _insert_key_to_unfull_tree(BTreeP &tree, int key);

// the problematic implementaion
_insert_key_to_unfull_tree(tree->getChild(i), key);
```

the compiler says cant cast BTreeNode * to BTreeP &, how should I fix this ?????

Answer (score 0):

`_insert_key_to_unfull_tree(*(tree->getChild(i)), key);`

Of course, you may want to verify getChild doesn't return null!

Comment: That would be "cannnot cast BTreeNode into BTreeP &"

Comment: Also I have a function _alloc_tree(BTreeP &tree), it works with a parameter of BTreeP type parameter

Answer (score 0):

The function `_insert_key_to_unfull_tree` expects a reference to a pointer:

```
void _insert_key_to_unfull_tree(BTreeNode*& tree, int key);
```

Try changing `getChild` so it returns a reference to a pointer:

```
BTreeNode*& getChild(const int i);
```

BTW you might want to remove `typedef BTreeNode* BTreeP` to reduce confusion.

Comment: I understand this typedef causes confusion, but a have a rather large number of code based on it.

Comment: And also,  BTreeNode* could be cast into const BTreeP &, and BTreeP could be cast into BTreeP&, I dont understand the difference......

Comment: I have a function _alloc_tree(BTreeP &tree), it works with a parameter of BTreeP type parameter